# WPF DataGrid can't be refreshed after cell edit

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I searched several times about `DataGrid` refresh problem. But can't get any idea about it. My problem is as below. Basically it can work.
**But if user sort columns and then edit cell, `DataGrid` can't bind.**  VS would list error `"{"Once AddNew or EditItem not allow “Sorting”。"}."`.

But it's friendly for user to be allowed to sort `DataGrid` columns. Please help me to address this problem. Thanks!

```
private void DataGrid1_CellEditEnding(object sender,
    DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    string sql="update table1 set field1='" + cell_value + '';
    BindGR();
}
private void BindGR()
{
    //Bind DataGrid
    if (dt != null)
    {
        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more code, like the source of the list how it is being sorted and all.

Comment: Thanks. My list is "select id, job_name, job_type,job_status from F_job " executed in MS SQL. And nothing changed after I amended SQL . So I think it should be wrong with DataGrid rendering problem. When I end cell editing, DataGrid begin rendering. At that time, I can't bind data to it.

Comment: There is a sorting event for datagrid. Handle that event and try to update the data in your source.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to handle this event? thanks

Comment: Ok I will post the code now. Please check and revert if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

**View.xaml**

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" 
             Sorting="DataGrid_OnSorting" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems, Mode="TwoWay"}">
 </DataGrid>
```

**View.xaml.cs**

```
    private ObservableCollection<DataClass> dataGridItems = new ObservableCollection<DataClass>();

    public ObservableCollection<DataClass> DataGridItems
    {
        get { return dataGridItems; }
        set { SetProperty(ref dataGridItems, value); }
    }
```

Please try with TwoWay binding ie Mode="TwoWay" for **Itemssource**

If it doesn't work, try code below. I did not test the code, since it is not fully implemented. Try to get an idea from this!

```
private void DataGrid_OnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    var sortedGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    foreach (var item in sortedGrid.Items)
    {
        DataGridItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your code. I tested them yesterday. Though they doesn't work, you give me some new idea. I would share it with you after debugging successfully.  On the other side, I wonder why the problem happens.

Comment: Yea, they might not work since I could not test it and it's not fully implemented version for me. So it's the basic idea to update list while sorting. Try it and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Item source update on `RowEditEnding` event, use `RowEditEnding` event instead of `CellEndEditing`, and on the column binding use `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding bindedProperty, StringFormat=n0,
                    Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
</DataGridTextColumn>
```